# I have user23, user24, etc. How to join 'user' and var num to refer to a single variable?

Tags: javascript

I have around 300 variables (user1, user2, user3...) with strings.

How can I refer to a variable, by using 'user' + numberofuser ?

I'm using javascript

Comment: Better: use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). (Although, so many duplicates.. [try this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+dynamic+variable))

Comment: sry, english is not my native language, and I'm 100% new to javascript, and I am 11 xDD

Answer (score 1):

If you assign user1, user2 another vairable, for example:

```
var listOfusers = {};
listOfusers.user1 = "abcd"
```

Then you can access `listOfusers.user1` like this:

```
var index = 1
listOfusers['user' + index]
```

Comment: Thanks so much I'll try that.

Comment: `listOfusers = {}` - creates an object/dictionary, not an array/list/sequence. I'd recommend an array: `var arrayOfUsers = []; arrayOfUsers[1] = ..` unless there is a need to key differently (such as off a user name). This also makes it easy to append a new user (`arrayOfUsers.push(..)`) without needing to determine the sequence id and allows well-ordered/stable traversal.

Answer (score 0):

you can use window[varname] to access variables defined in global scope

```
var user1 =1,
  user2 = 2,
  user3 = 3

var v_name = 'user' + 2; 

console.log(window[v_name])
```

output

```
2
```